# Python most effiecient method of re-arranging numpy array of Dict

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary

The following code creates a dict of this format

```
{'a': array([1, 2...1000]), 'b': array([1, 2...1000])....

old_dict = dict(a=np.array([]),
           b=np.array([]),
           c=np.array([]),
           new_dict=np.array([]),
           e=np.array([]),
           f=np.array([]),
           g=np.array([]),
           h=np.array([]))

for x in range(10000):
    old_dict['a'] = np.append(old_dict['a'], x)
    old_dict['b'] = np.append(old_dict['b'], x)
    old_dict['c'] = np.append(old_dict['c'], x)
    old_dict['d'] = np.append(old_dict['d'], x)
    old_dict['e'] = np.append(old_dict['e'], x)
    old_dict['f'] = np.append(old_dict['f'], x)
    old_dict['g'] = np.append(old_dict['g'], x)
    old_dict['h'] = np.append(old_dict['h'], x)
```

I want to convert this dict into a list of dicts that looks like this

```
[{'a': 1, 'b': 1....}, {'a': 2, 'b': 2....},.....]
```

I have come up with this code

```
new_list_dict = []
for i, (key, val) in enumerate(old_dict.items()):
   _d = {}
   for k, v in old_dict.items():
      _d[k] = v[i]
   new_list_dict.append(_d)
```

but can you suggest the fastest (vectorized?) way to do this ?

Comment: `items()` is the closest we get to 'vectorizing' access to a dictionary.  You can't 'vectorize' the `d[k]=v` dictionary setting, though I believe there is a way of creating a dictionary from a list of keys and a list of values (I don't do advance dictionary work).  For what it's worth, you initial dictionary creation is slow.  `np.append` in a loop is SLOW.  List append is much better.

Comment: Are you interested in creating code that has these exact numbers?  Or are the numbers 1 through 1000 just stand-ins for the real data?

Comment: They are stand ins for real data, and the vales of the real data are a mix between strings, ints and floats. (This data was initially all in a pandas df which I have migrated away from due to poor performance) The initial dict is created in an entirely different way and I am happy with the performance of how that is created.

Comment: How about `k,V = old_dict.keys(),old_dict.values()`     `[dict(zip(k,v)) for v in zip(*V)]`?